# View UV seams over creased edges

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view

I'm currently UV unwrapping a model with creased edges. The problem is, when I mark UV seams on the same edges that I have creased, the edge is only highlighted in purple, for the crease, but the red highlighting for the seam does not show up. Example:

[image]

In the above picture, both indicated edges are seams but the bottom one does not have the red highlighting. While the seams still work when I unwrap, it is really inconvenient to have to remember where I put them.

**Is there some way I can either change the draw order of these two overlays or make both appear at the same time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to alter the code used to build blender to make it draw the highlights differently.

You can however toggle the display of each highlight separately, so you only see one at a time. In the 3DView Properties region <kbd>N</kbd> you can find the mesh display panel -

[image: mesh display options]

Note that the mesh display settings are unique to each object, not a global setting.